# Display directory of images at public html using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put all the images in a directory all together using html with php. I have a file `my.php` in the same directory as the images I want to display (stored on a private remote server that has a publicly accessible directory via html). The code is quite simple:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php
    $files = scandir('./');
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
            echo "<img src='$file' width=200 />";
        }
    }
?>
</html>
```

If you run the snippet above, you can see that this block outputs all the code after the `>` in the echo line: `"; } } ?>`. This seems to completely miss the contents of the echo call. Another note: it has worked for someone else on another machine, but it does not work for me on mine. I am unsure what could be causing this specific issue, or why it might run differently on different machines.. This is really my first parlay into php and html, so would really appreciate a detailed answer if anyone has one!

Comment: 1. You said "web server", is the server running on the cloud or is the server running on your localhost ? 2. You also said "uploading directory of images" but can you show the upload image part ?

Comment: @KenLee 1. apologies, "web server" may not have been the right terminology. It is a remote private server that has a single publicly accessible directory via html. 2. upload was the wrong word, I meant to say "display already existing images which are in the same directory"

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem description. Describe what happens and what you expect to happen, and include the complete text of any error messages you see.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I appreciate that I could have been clearer in my description of the problem. However, your edit to the question removed the ability to run the code snippet, which displayed the problem. I will make the proper edits to clarify.

Comment: You can't run PHP in a code snippet here (they're entirely client-side based. Were you expecting it to scan the contents of the stackoverflow server and display it to us??) so no the edit didn't do any harm.  The snippet isn't showing anything meaningful in terms of demonstrating whatever issue you have on your real machine. Perhaps simply PHP is not installed on it? And/or you haven't placed the code in a .php file so the webserver would treat it as code?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the clarification. I don't know all the underlying details of either of these things since I'm very new to all of this, all I know is that when I hit `Run code snippet` in stack overflow on that bit, I get the exact same output as I get on my machine, which is why I have left it in. I suspect that means my issue is an html problem and not a php one..?

Comment: No it probably means your server is doing exactly what the snippet is doing - i.e. not executing the PHP. And because of the `<` at the start of PHP, the browser then gets a bit confused and isn't sure which bits are HTML tags and which are content, hence the odd output. I updated my comment above too, please refresh.

Comment: Well then, I guess in a sense, putting the code in the snippet was the best thing I could have done to understand my problem.

Comment: Perhaps so, in a weird way :-). Although simply pasting in the output from your server into the question, along with the code, would serve the same kind of purpose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234429/discussion-between-cadams-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works on my Apache server.

Try to replace
`echo "<img src='$file' width=200 />";`
with

```
     echo "<img src='".$file."' width=200 />";
```

quote in quote is generally a bad idea. Mith be interpreter specific.

Idea is that single quote is opened in first string, variable is passed and then the single quote is closed in second string .

Comment: To what benefit should this idea be? The variable substitution in the string did work fine earlier on.  The added concatenation you suggest could have some benefit if extended more, but that was not suggested. For example, using htmlspecialchars to actually encode a HTML/XHTML attribute value for `$file` - which is missing in the original example (but is not the cause of the OPs problems - see the comments, it's resolved by activating PHP on the server - it was not in the beginning - but on your server, where it worked)

Comment: I did not know that SO snippets does not support PHP at all. Anyway.. tried stripped snipped on several online PHP snipet emulators and the echo " '$variable'  " passes the variable on all 5 of them. Such validators have lots of restrictions. Question-> answer, right? Have to replace my old glass ball. The current one gets too blurred ;)

Comment: yeah, you at least did execute it on a system you _knew_ php is being executed, this bar was already too high for the OP. I'm sure your idea was with best intentions, thats why I left a comment so you at least for yourself may have a benefit.